# Typoscript output not utf8?

Tags: text, utf-8, typo3, typoscript

the config:

```
page.config {
        additionalHeaders = Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
        metaCharset = utf-8
        renderCharset = utf-8
}
```

and this here:

```
page.10.marks {
    FOO = TEXT
    FOO.value = ÜüÖöÄäß
}
```

the output is the "riddle" sign. also in the source code. There are more markers i need to fill with special characters for other languages later. whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set in the localconf.php:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['setDBinit'] = 'SET NAMES utf8;'.chr(10).'SET SESSION character_set_server=utf8;';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['forceCharset'] = 'utf8';
```

However, this (probably) requires that collation of the database tables is set to UTF8, e.g. **utf8_general_ci**. If you are starting a project, set the collation. If it's a running website, **[convert the data](http://wiki.typo3.org/UTF-8_support#Convert_an_already_existing_database_to_UTF-8)** before you do the settings in the localconf.php.

**WARNING**: If it's a running website, test it first on a copy.

Comment: thanks thats a solution! but it was the wrong one for my problem. i havent noticed my Typo3 saving text in ISO... and so i changed all the charsets to ISO ;P ... how stupid sometimes

Answer (score 0):

In the Installtool you need to enable forceCharset=utf8 and in the localconf.php`$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS'][' setDBinit'] = 'set names utf8' and ini_set('default_charset = utf-8'). Source: http://wiki.typo3.org/UTF-8_support.

Comment: already in localconf.php

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['forceCharset'] = 'utf8';